# Prevent html injection in a asp mvc dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a website that has several drop-down-lists, all are created from a database lookup.

These controls have simple model state validation and this all works as expected.

However, I have noticed that if I add an extra item to the drop-down list on the client this appears to still get submitted correctly. is there a way I can validate this or do I need to add a custom validation property on my drop downs to support this?

I am using asp.net MVC 5 with an entity framework 6 storage.

Comment: Do you mean you want to validate that the posted value is one of the possible values you originally sent to the view?

Comment: You should *always* validate the posted data. ASP.NET MVC makes this easy with data annotations and validators. You *can't* prevent the browser from submitting anything it wants through the console or, eg. Fiddler

Comment: yeah i want to validate that it was one of the posted values

Comment: Then in the POST method you need to check that - `bool isValid = db.yourTable.Any(x => x.someProperty == yourPostedValue);`